# Let n ≥ 2. Prove that the linear congruence nx ≡ b (mod n + 1) has a unique solution mod n + 1 for any b ∈ Z.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I cannot formulate a proof that yields the results of a unique solution. If someone could please guide me through a proof I would be most thankful!

Comment: gcd($n,n+1)=1$ so $n$ is invertible modulo $n+1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, I see. This is because Z(subscript n+1) is {0, 1,..., n}, meaning that n is the largest number in mod n+1 and is therefore the unique solution since it is multiplied by an integer x. (I know that's not a formal proof or anything I'm just trying to see if I'm on the right path.)

Comment: $nx\equiv-x\pmod{n+1}$.

Comment: Hint: mod arithmetic is often simpler using *least magnitude* reps, e.g. $\,0,\pm1,\pm2 \pmod{\!5}.\,$ In the OP we have  $\bmod n\!+\!1\!:\,\ n\!+\!1\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, \,n\equiv -1\,$ so $\,n\,$ has least magnitude rep $-1,\,$ which is self-inverse.

Comment: @Shailesh:  since $n$ is invertible, you could multiply both sides of $nx\equiv b$ by the inverse of $n$ -- which others have indicated is itself (mod $n+1$) -- to get the solution to $nx\equiv b$, and also show uniqueness:  $nx_1\equiv nx_2\implies x_1\equiv x_2$